# Android ImageView with drawable not always rendering

Tags: android, listview, imageview, drawable

I have an ImageView object that I'm setting the android:src="@drawable/some_xml_file" instead of a standard png and it seems to not always render the drawable, as you can see in the first row here (it also happens intermittently in other rows as well):[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d09b549a9d.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d09b549a9d.jpg)

I've tried setting the src & the background property but they both have the same effect. the source code from my list view row item is this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/action_button" android:background="@drawable/action_box"
    android:layout_width="25dip" android:layout_height="25dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />
```

then my res/drawable/action_box.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
       <gradient

            android:startColor="#81c557"
            android:endColor="#539942" 
            android:angle="270"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip"  android:color="#a8d78a"  />
```

Comment: Are you overriding, or doing anything special in the getView method of your ListView adapter?

Comment: Have you used `hierarchyviewer` to determine if your `ImageView` is missing, invisible, drawn off-screen, etc.?

Comment: was this ever resolved? You also don't need to use ImageView; you could just use View with a android:background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this, and the issue was related to conditions in the getView() method.  I basically learned the hardway that you should always explictly handle all cases when you set visibility / width etc.

Comment: You learn quickly that if you recycle views, you must reset *all* properties that may differ between states, and you should provide a method(s) to do so such that you can transition from any one state to another with no hassle.